# Flutter text animation on page view scroll

Tags: flutter, animation, mobile

Reference link: https://dribbble.com/shots/15798418-Mobile-App-Onboarding

I have been trying to build the above UI using Page view. I have used the stack as parent widget and handling the image scroll using page controller offset value.

Not sure how to achieve the text animation(In and out) and what could be the trigger point to start the animation for current page?

Answer (score 0):

The animations package from the Flutter team has a nice package that includes an animation that closely resembles your example.

Here is the package: https://pub.dev/packages/animations

It is the first example under Shared Axis. They also have good examples of how to implement the animation using this package. If you have issues using the package please add some code samples for the problem and we can help!